# Sort data in ListView get from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I want sort data in ListView that get from SQLite with `getAllContacts()`

```
  public List<News> getAllContacts() {
    String[] yek_name = new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NID, KEY_ONVAN, KEY_MATN, KEY_Tarikh,
             KEY_FAV, KEY_KHAND, KEY_NNEW, KEY_SUBJ, KEY_SUBJID };

    Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, yek_name, null, null, null,
            null, KEY_ID + " DESC");

    List<News> nams = cursorToList(cursor);
    return nams;
}
```

i use Order By -> `KEY_ID + " DESC"` but not work and when use `KEY_ID + " ASC"` can not change in ListView
Can you please check where has it gone wrong.

**News.java**

```
public class News implements Parcelable {
    private int id;
    private int nid;
    private String ntitle;
    private String ntext;
    private String ndata;
    private int fav;
    private int khande;
    private int nnew;
    private int subj;
    private int subjid;

    public News(){

    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getnId(){
        return nid;
    }
    public void setnId(int nid){
        this.nid = nid;
    }
    public String getOnvan(){
        return ntitle;
    }
    public void setOnvan(String onvan){
        this.ntitle = onvan;
    }
    public String getMatn (){
        return ntext;
    }
    public void setMatn(String matn){
        this.ntext = matn;
    }
    public String getTarikh(){
        return ndata;
    }
    public void setTarikh(String tarikh){
        this.ndata = tarikh;
    }
    public int getFav(){
        return fav;
    }
    public void setFav(int fav){
        this.fav = fav;
    }
    public int getKhande(){
        return khande;
    }
    public void setKhande(int khande){
        this.khande = khande;
    }

    public int getnNew(){
        return nnew;
    }
    public void setnNew(int nnew){
        this.nnew = nnew;
    }

    public int getSubject(){
        return subj;
    }
    public void setSubject(int subject){
        this.subj = subject;
    }

    public int getSubjectid(){
        return subjid;
    }
    public void setSubjectid(int subjectid){
        this.subjid = subjectid;
    }

    public News (Parcel in){
        id = in.readInt();
        nid = in.readInt();
        ntitle = in.readString();
        ntext = in.readString();
        ndata = in.readString();
        fav = in.readInt();
        khande = in.readInt();
        nnew= in.readInt();
        subj= in.readInt();
        subjid= in.readInt();
    }
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel fet, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        fet.writeInt(id);
        fet.writeInt(nid);
        fet.writeString(ntitle);
        fet.writeString(ntext);
        fet.writeString(ndata);
        fet.writeInt(fav);
        fet.writeInt(khande);
        fet.writeInt(nnew);
        fet.writeInt(subj);
        fet.writeInt(subjid);
    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<News> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<News>() {

        @Override
        public News createFromParcel(Parcel arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new News(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public News[] newArray(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new News[arg0];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: it's make error -> E/AndroidRuntime(1413): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.sheikhoo.ekhteraat_app/ir.sheikhoo.ekhteraat_app.GetActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ORDER": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id, nid, ntitle, ntext, ndata, fav, khande, nnew, subj, subjid FROM news ORDER BY  ORDER BY id DESC

Comment: it's make 2 ORDER BY -> " ORDER BY ORDER BY id DESC"

Comment: Last paragraph in your question is not clear, at least not to me!

Comment: dont use "ORDER BY": it is added automatically to a select statement

Comment: @pskink,yes it's true

Comment: @PareshMayani ,I mean,the last parameter of 'db.query' not work correctly

Comment: Your query right:
I have one alternative 

public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<News> {
    @Override
    public int compare(News ob1, News ob2) {
        return ob1.id.compareTo(ob2.id);
    }
}

and then call 

Collections.sort(yourlistname, new CustomComparator())

Comment: @kulvinder,it's make error with int data, `Cannot invoke compareTo(int) on the primitive type int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use Collections for it.If you want to short the Object of bean class than use it in this way.

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Object>(){

            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                ContactPhone p1 = (ContactPhone) o1;
                ContactPhone p2 = (ContactPhone) o2;
               return p1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getName());
            }

        });
```

Otherwise for Strings just use :

```
Collections.sort(contactList, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Comment: can you give more details,I could not solve the problem

Comment: what is News in
List<News> nams = cursorToList(cursor);
i think its a bean class.

Comment: Fetch the raw data(simple without ORDER) and sort the list after getting the records.

Comment: `public List<News> getAllContacts() {

........

    List<News> nams = cursorToList(cursor);
Collections.sort(nams, new Comparator<Object>(){

            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                News p1 = (News) o1;
                News p2 = (News) o2;
               return p1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getName());
            }

        });



    return nams;
}`

Comment: tnx,add 'News' class in top post.i want sort by id and relapse getId with getName -> "return p1.getId().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getId());" but mack error -> 'Cannot invoke compareToIgnoreCase(int) on the primitive type int'

Comment: use `return (p1.getId() - p2.getId());`  in place of `p1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getName());`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82793/discussion-between-sadegh-and-sourabh-bans).